# How can I calculate the column sums of an dynamic array in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have a dynamic array names 'MyArray' that has no headers and only number values in its columns. How can I calculate the column sums of that dynamic array with a single formula in only one cell so that it returns another dynamic array listing all the column sums.

Here is a simple example table:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 584 | 393 |
| 139 | 369 | 925 |
| 670 | 5 | 584 |
| 445 | 23 | 400 |

where the column sums then are 1268, 981 and 2302, which I calculated by dragging a simple `SUM()` function beneath the columns from left to right

So given that this table without headers is a dynamic array named 'MyArray', how can I calculate those sums with a single formula in only one cell dynamically?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BYCOL` and `LAMDA`:

```
=BYCOL(F1#,LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))
```

[image]

I put your values in A1:C4 then to make it an array formula output I put in F1, `=A1:C4` which spilled the array.